# Generically aggregate columns using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying generically aggregate data using data.table package. I have multiple columns that I want to aggregate. I create a initial data table using the following script:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x.1 = rnorm(10, 20, 3), x.2 = rnorm(10, 20, 3), x.3 = rnorm(10, 20, 3),
                 y.1 = rnorm(10, 20, 3), y.2 = rnorm(10, 20, 3), y.3 = rnorm(10, 20, 3),
                 z.1 = rnorm(10, 20, 3), z.2 = rnorm(10, 20, 3), z.3 = rnorm(10, 20, 3))
```

What I am trying to achieve is to aggregate columns {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3} => {x.total, y.total, z.total} by applying sum to each group of columns.

I can do this using for loops like this:

```
prefixes <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
initial.colnames <- c(names(dt))

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  for (pref in prefixes){
    dt[,eval(paste0(pref, '.total')) := sum(dt[i, eval(grep(pref, initial.colnames))]), with = TRUE]
  }
}
```

However, I want to apply using in-line data table construct, something like this:

```
dt[, eval(paste0(prefixes, '.total')) := sum(dt[,eval(grep(prefixes, initial.colnames))]), with = F]
```

But this does not give me the required results.

Maybe there are some ideas how would I do that in the right way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you call "working". Did you check the new "total" columns? they have same values regardless of the values of `dt`. What is the desired output? Row sums per prefixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `Reduce`

```
dt[,paste0(prefixes, '.total'):= Map(function(i)  Reduce('+',as.list(.SD[,i, with=FALSE])), 
                                split(names(dt), sub('\\..*', '', names(dt))))]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to aggregate with `melt`:

```
mDT = melt(dt[, r := .I], measure.vars = patterns(prefixes), value.name=prefixes)

mDT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=r, .SDcols=prefixes]


     r        x        y        z
 1:  1 63.65898 65.41892 56.40470
 2:  2 60.58634 62.71055 48.69771
 3:  3 50.12036 60.06289 66.38637
 4:  4 55.42629 63.38670 56.98914
 5:  5 59.94042 54.28727 49.20218
 6:  6 59.51313 67.53499 59.24097
 7:  7 63.26874 62.23262 60.70875
 8:  8 54.90082 76.09135 58.79787
 9:  9 56.35402 52.11372 60.37903
10: 10 52.77926 55.06044 53.75093
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, it works for this exemplar data table, however, once I have large table melt function creates more new columns than I have unique column suffixes. Please let me know if this comment makes sense, otherwise, I will try to include sample of data that I am working with

Comment: @LaurynasStašys I'm not sure why that would happen. Maybe best to post a new question if you're wondering how to get around that problem.

Comment: Well, this is the same problem that I mentioned in the question, however, its easier for me to create sample data table rather than have a sample data with 200 columns

Comment: @LaurynasStašys Do you need 200 columns to illustrate the problem? Better to create sample data that reproduces the issue and (I think) post as a new question, even if it is essentially "the same problem." It's the usual etiquette here not to substantially change the question being asked such that existing answers no longer work... but you can do it if you want. I've reached the cap for answer deletions today, but can delete this tomorrow if you do so (and I can't figure out how to make it work).